# C# Download of Email - Attachments not found

Tags: c#, email, outlook

I'm using the EWS Managed API to download an email, and I manage to download the e-mail itself without issue. I can verify it's the correct email via the EmailMessage.From.Name and EmailMessage.Subject.

However when looking at it in Outlook it has an attachment, but the .Net object has EmailMessage.HasAttachments set to false, and EmailMessage.Attachments.Count equal to zero.

Why would I be able to see the attachment in Outlook, but not via the .Net object?

Code I have is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data;

namespace CiscoPrimeInfrastructureDataAccess
{
    public static class EmailFetcher
    {
        private const string _EMAIL = @"foo@bar.com";
        private const string _USERNAME = "foo";
        private const string _PASSWORD = "bar123";
        private const string _DOMAIN = "bar";
        private const string _SUBJECT = "foobar subject";

        public static string GetCurrentPrimeCsv()
        {
            string inboxFolder = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Inbox"];

            if (!File.Exists(inboxFolder))
                File.Create(inboxFolder);

            var service = CreateExchangeService();

            var newestInventoryReport = GetNewestInventoryEmail(service);

            Console.WriteLine("From: {0}{1}Subject: {2}{3}Number of Attachments: {4}", newestInventoryReport.From.Name, Environment.NewLine, newestInventoryReport.Subject, Environment.NewLine, newestInventoryReport.Attachments.Count);

            FileAttachment attachment = newestInventoryReport.Attachments[0] as FileAttachment;

            string guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

            string downloadFilePath = Path.Combine(inboxFolder, guid + "_" + attachment.FileName);
            string extractedFilePath = Path.Combine(inboxFolder, guid + "_extracted.csv");

            attachment.Load(Path.Combine(downloadFilePath));

            ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(downloadFilePath, extractedFilePath);

            string csv = String.Empty;

            using (var reader = new StreamReader(extractedFilePath))
            {
                csv = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }

            return csv;
        }



        private static ExchangeService CreateExchangeService()
        {
            ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);
            service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(_USERNAME, _PASSWORD, _DOMAIN);

            service.AutodiscoverUrl(_EMAIL);

            return service;
        }


        private static EmailMessage GetNewestInventoryEmail(ExchangeService service)
        {
            var firstSeveralEmails = GetFirstSeveralEmails(service);

            EmailMessage newestEmail = null;

            foreach (var email in firstSeveralEmails)
            {
                if (email.Subject.Contains(_SUBJECT))
                {
                    if (newestEmail == null || email.DateTimeReceived > newestEmail.DateTimeReceived)
                    {
                        newestEmail = email;
                    }
                }
            }

            return newestEmail;
        }

        private static IEnumerable<EmailMessage> GetFirstSeveralEmails(ExchangeService service)
        {
            Mailbox mailbox = new Mailbox(_EMAIL);
            FolderId inboxFolderId = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, mailbox);

            FindItemsResults<Item> findItemsResults = service.FindItems(inboxFolderId, new ItemView(128));

            return findItemsResults.OfType<EmailMessage>().Select(findEmailResult => findEmailResult as EmailMessage).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What displays here: `Console.WriteLine("From: {0}{1}Subject: {2}{3}Number of Attachments: {4}", newestInventoryReport.From.Name, Environment.NewLine, newestInventoryReport.Subject, Environment.NewLine, newestInventoryReport.Attachments.Count);`

Comment: From: Christell, Canin<return> Subject: foobar subject<return> Number of Attachments: 0

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used EWS so this might be wrong.

I'd have look at the body of the email. Attachments actually get transmitted in the body, usually as base64-encoded strings, with mime marks before and after the encoded data to distinguish different files. EWS may not have processed these in the object you're getting. It's possible that, as you're getting an Item and casting to EnailMessage, the EmailMessage hasn't been processed fully to e.g. extract attachments. Note that the docs say:

[Use the Bind(ExchangeService, ItemId) method to bind to an existing e-mail message on the Exchange server.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.emailmessage.emailmessage%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx)

That might help.